# App.yaml configuration for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I wonder if the following configuration is correct and the handlers are in the right order:

```
application: myAppName
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: website/index.html
  upload: website/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: website
```

Inside the `website` folder I have the following:

- images_folder
- favicon.ico
- index.html

One more thing: do I need to handle `favicon.ico` separately like [this](https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/):

```
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon\.ico
```

or maybe:

```
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
```

Comment: This is a configuration, not code itself. There is no program to review here, please see [Do configuration files constitute reviewable code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6061/52915).